# How to create dot plot with both negative and positive axes?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a r data frame and would like to make a dot plot in ggplot where x-axis would correspond to different groups present in Ensembl_ID row ("ENSG00000000003", "ENSG00000000005" etc. are the group for x-axis) and y-axis would correspond to respective numbers present in logFC.1 to logFC.9. I would like to display the logFC.1 to logFC.9 number of each respective group in form of dots like the attached image (to prevent confusion, each group should have the same color and only change with intensity like: if the mean x is bigger it gets more red and if the mean y is bigger it gets more green or something).

If possible then can you guys also help me in assigning the different color for positive and negative values.

Can we also assign the dot's color based on value (color intensity)?

```
df1 <- data.frame(Ensembl_ID = c("ENSG00000000003", "ENSG00000000005", "ENSG00000000419", "ENSG00000000457", "ENSG00000000460", "ENSG00000000938", "ENSG00000000971", "ENSG00000001036", "ENSG00000001084", "ENSG00000001167" ), logFC.1 = c(0.147447019707984, -0.278643924528991, 0.00638502079233481, 0.00248371473862579, 0.0591639590814736, -0.0892578080659792, -0.0139042150604349, 0.15210410748665, -0.0273174541997048, 0.0373813166759115 ), logFC.2 = c(0.14237211045168, -0.153847067952652, 0.00806519294435945, -0.0243298183425441, 0.0639184480028851, -0.0791126460573967, -0.0517704622015086, 0.100033161692714, 0.105136768894399, 0.0509474174745926 ), logFC.3 = c(0.0692402101693023, -0.212626837128185, 0.0665466667502187, 0.0189664498456434, 0.073631371224761, -0.0642014520794086, 0.0115060035255512, 0.104767159584613, 0.140378485980222, 0.0814931176279395), logFC.4 = c(0.175916688982428, -0.0606440302201137, 0.0862627141013101, 0.105179938123113, 0.128866411791584, -0.0988927171791539, 0.128758540724723, 0.0997656895899759, 0.345468063926355, 0.130898388184307), logFC.5 = c(0.144743421921328, 0.247159332221974, 0.0232237466183996, 0.0800788300610377, 0.178887735169961, -0.0592727391427514, -0.0723099661837084, 0.0387715967173523, -0.0607793368610136, 0.110464511693512), logFC.6 = c(0.0848187321362019, -0.299283590551811, 0.0366788808661408, -0.00763280370062748, 0.0145148270035513, -0.0384916970002755, -0.0000335640771631606, 0.0851895375297912, -0.00364050261322463, 0.0602143760128463), logFC.7 = c(0.305256444042024, -0.274308408751318, 0.0977066795857243, -0.0265659018074027, 0.136348613124811, -0.0938364533000299, -0.143634179166262, 0.139913812601005, 0.268708965044232, 0.133427360632365), logFC.8 = c(0.12744808339884, -0.285015311267508, 0.0459140048745496, -0.00976012971218515, 0.13292412700208, -0.184687147498946, -0.0411558715447517, 0.165717944056239, 0.323358546432839, 0.0502386767987279), logFC.9 = c(0.286824598926274, 0.095530985319937, 0.101370835445593, 0.0352336819150421, 0.0573659992830985, -0.0739779010955875, 0.00466993628480923, 0.0486643748696862, 0.0322601740536419, 0.0873158516027886))
```

[image: Sample Image of expected output]

This is the only test sample, in real data, each group has 1500-2000 values so if dot merging over each other is not an issue.

Thank you for your kind help. waiting to hear from you peoples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. bring your data in long format
2. define a mid point `mean`
3. use  `geom_jitter` to account for overlaying points
4. map the color and specify `scale_color_gradient2`

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df1 %>% 
    pivot_longer(
        cols = -Ensembl_ID
    )

mid <- mean(df$value)

ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(Ensembl_ID), y = value, color=value)) +
    geom_jitter(size=4, 
                position = position_jitter(width = 0.2, height = 0.2)) +
    #scale_color_gradient(low="blue", high="red")
    scale_color_gradient2(midpoint=mid, low="blue", mid="grey",
                          high="red", space ="Lab" )+
    theme_classic()
```

Comment: TarJae Dear, Thank you so much for your time. It is really good, and working as needed. Thank you so much. Have a good day dear

Comment: Just a small question, can we change the thickness of the bar (which hold dots) without changing the dot size, like small dots are placed randomly with respect to y-axis ? If so then what function should I include?

Comment: You can try: change: `geom_jitter(size=4, 
                position = position_jitter(width = 0.2, height = 0.2)) +` to `geom_jitter(size=4, width = 0.35)+` this. Then you can adapt width?!

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(-Ensembl_ID) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(grp_avg = mean(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%     # EDIT -- sort should happen outside groups
  mutate(name = fct_reorder(name, grp_avg)) %>%
  

ggplot(aes(Ensembl_ID, y = value, color = name)) +
  ggbeeswarm::geom_beeswarm() +
  scale_color_brewer() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 20))
```

[image]

Comment: What do you thin about `geom_jitter`?

Comment: It's great; looks like OP's example used something with a deterministic x adjustment so I went with that.

Comment: Jon Spring Dear, Thank you for your time but it is not what I wanted. Anyway, Jon already solved the problem so thanks for your effort and time. I am sorry if my question was confusing.